# need some advice when converting python2.7 to python3 script

Tags: python-3.x, module, named

I'm trying to rewrite python script from python 2.7.x on raspbian stretch   to python 3.9.x on raspbian bullseye and i already check  what  python modules and all deb packages related to python are installed on stretch.

so original script is starting like that :

```
import socket, struct, fcntl, subprocess, sys, time, os, IN, pygame
from random import randrange
```

I already manage to find and change all other modules names to correspond python3 but I still can not find a proper module to ---> IN

Can someone help me with this  as i'm not a programmer and this is quite new to me.

on Debian stretch where script is installed  I already checked  all python packages  with dpkg -L|grep python   and i installed  a proper ones for python3 on bullseye.
I also done pip list  and pip freeze to check what modules are in debian strech  to install all in debian bullseye  but now bullseye have same modules and i still can not run this script :(

line 1, in 
import socket, struct, fcntl, subprocess, sys, time, os, IN, pygame
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'IN'

thx for any help

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

so i located this module in debian stretch by using some script to find python module that i found on stackoverflow

```
import IN
print(IN.__file__)
```

and the results is :

```
# python find_module.py 
/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-arm-linux-gnueabihf/IN.pyc
```

and now i don't know how to install something like this IN.pyc  in to python3 as I can not find something like that for python3.

I assume that this was a part of python2.7 installation and now it is not included in python3 right ?